Calculated table isn't working the correct way anymore?
I have a calculated table within a report that consists of the latest 12 months revenue and a total of those 12 months. This automatically updates when the data is refreshed. The code used for the calculated table is shown below:
Previous12MonthsRevenue = {
    ("P12M TR", NAMEOF(NewMeasures[LYPrev12MonthRevenue]), 13),
    ([LatestMonth], NAMEOF(NewMeasures[LatestMonthRev]), 12),
    ([LatestMonth-1], NAMEOF(NewMeasures[LatestMonthRev-1]), 11),
    ([LatestMonth-2], NAMEOF(NewMeasures[LatestMonthRev-2]), 10),
    ([LatestMonth-3], NAMEOF(NewMeasures[LatestMonthRev-3]), 9),
    ([LatestMonth-4], NAMEOF(NewMeasures[LatestMonthRev-4]), 8),
    ([LatestMonth-5], NAMEOF(NewMeasures[LatestMonthRev-5]), 7),
    ([LatestMonth-6], NAMEOF(NewMeasures[LatestMonthRev-6]), 6),
    ([LatestMonth-7], NAMEOF(NewMeasures[LatestMonthRev-7]), 5),
    ([LatestMonth-8], NAMEOF(NewMeasures[LatestMonthRev-8]), 4),
    ([LatestMonth-9], NAMEOF(NewMeasures[LatestMonthRev-9]), 3),
    ([LatestMonth-10], NAMEOF(NewMeasures[LatestMonthRev-10]), 2),
    ([LatestMonth-11], NAMEOF(NewMeasures[LatestMonthRev-11]), 1)
};

The [LatestMonth] [...-1] etc, are measures which returns the month and year in "mmm-yy" format to display as dynamic column headers
And the [LatestMonthRev] [...-1], etc are measures which calculate  the sum of the revenue for that filtered date.
Both these measure work individually
I added this into the columns field on a table visual within power BI. The image below shows how the table used to function, this occurred as soon as you dragged the first column of the calculated table into the table visual with 0 formatting:

When trying to recreate this table visual within a new report with the same data an issue occurs. The DAX function works and produces the same calculated table, however, when inserting the column into a table visual it shows like the screenshot below:

My question is: Does anyone know how to rectify this issue to enable the calculated table to function the way it used to?
UPDATE dummy data here so you guys can help!
https://shorturl.at/YDHuH

Can you please provide some data ?

@AmiraBedhiafi what sort of data do you need? I essentially need the latest 12 month revenue to look like the first table screenshot like it used to but it is behaving like the second screenshot now

The data you are working on. Posting data as picture won't help us to help you.

UPDATE, I just had a chat with my boss and I can't give access to the data due to the sensitive info I can't share, do you have any suggestions on how to help from just the screenshots

No need to provide real data you can provide dummy data. Sharing data as images will lead to get your question closed

so essentially if I was to provide access to an excel sheet with dummy data from the previous 12 months, would that be sufficient to allow you to experiment regarding answering this question

I have added a link to dummy data in the question! looking forward to seeing if anyone can help! the link is also here https://shorturl.at/YDHuH
